# Puppet cli and list of variables

Tags: list, module, puppet

First time asking after a long time reading. :)

I am trying to write a puppet module with a list of packages to install using a shell command (Cannot use the package module as the packages are installed using conda).

```
  class deep_learning {
  $deep_learning_package_list = [ 'numpy' , 'pandas' ]

  $deep_learning_package_list.each |$deep_learning_package| {
    command  => '/opt/mambaforge/bin/conda install $deep_learning_package',
    provider => shell,
    }
  } 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error message is thrown?

Comment: the error is a syntax error
  `Server Error: Syntax error at '=>'
    at line 5`
line 5 is the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this using one variable and a command:

```
  class deep_learning {
  $deep_learning_package_list = "numpy pandas"

  exec { "/opt/mambaforge/bin/conda install -y ${deep_learning_package_list}":
  }
  }
```